# Smallest $a$ such that both $a$ and $a+5$ and $a$ and $a+7$ have a common factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Which is the smallest integer number $a$  so that the highest common factor of $a$ and $a+5$ is not $1$ and the highest common factor of $a$ and $a+7$ is not $1$ either?

I think that it is $35$. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

Since the highest common factor of $a$ and $a+5$ is the same as that of $a$ and $(a+5) - a = 5$, one needs $5 \mid a$ for it not to be $1$. 
Likewise you need $7 \mid a$.

So, $5$ and $7$ divide $a$, and the result you claimed follows in one more step.

(This assumes that you are looking for a positive solution. If you allows  negative numbers there is no smallest one, as any multiple of $35$ would work. So $-35$, $-350$, $-35000000000000000$ and so on. )